# Update rightBarButtonItems when segmented control change

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, controls, uibarbuttonitem

I want to hide/show a UIBarButtonItem when a segmentedControl changes, this is my code:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleSegmentedChange() {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case index0:
            // Set the proper rightBarButtonItems, in the first load this bar button items will be nil, this is why we have to check first
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Filter2"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(openBottomSheet)))

        default:
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.remove(at: 0)
        }
    }
```

However is not updating the views (hiding or showing anything).

**Note** I've also tried setting the `rightBarButtonItems` to nil before adding or removing items, however is not working.

How can I accomplish the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

If `rightBarButtonItems` is nil before you try to append or remove items to/from it, then nothing will happen as you cannot append or remove items to/from a non-existent array.

Instead of appending/removing to/from `rightBarButtonItems`, try just setting it directly to the items you want it to be, like this:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleSegmentedChange() {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Filter2"),
                                            style: .plain,
                                            target: self,
                                            action: #selector(openBottomSheet))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barButtonItem]
        // Note: If you're just dealing with one bar button item, 
        // you could also just use `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` like:
        // navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem

    default:
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil // or `= []`
        // Note: If you're just dealing with one bar button item, 
        // you could also just use `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` like:
        // navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and nothing changed, my guess is that the navigation item is not being updated, but I don't think that is the root of the problem

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Then there must be an additional problem somewhere else, as this works for me in a quick sample app I just made. Make sure `handleSegmentedChange` is actually being called, make sure you have an image named `Filter2` in your assets folder, etc.

Comment: Also, your code has `index0` in it, which I assumed was a typo and you meant just `0` - but if it's not a typo, then it must be some property or variable you have, so make sure `index0` is actually a number that represents one of `segmentedControl`'s indices.

Comment: Also – if you're tapping on an already-selected segment, then `handleSegmentedChange` will not be called, so you might have to tap the other segment first, then tap the first segment. (Or set the first segment to be unselected from the start.)